# How to round or convert a float value to int with bc? getting: "(standard_in) 1: syntax error"

Tags: shell-script, variable, conversion, bc, floating-point

I will get value like 2743410360.320 and I want value like 2743410360 to a variable.

I tried

```
INTValueOfGB=$ echo "($gb+0.5)/1" | bc
```

But I am getting   `(standard_in) 1: syntax error`

Comment: Please check that your code's syntax is still the one you intended to post after I edited it. (That solitary `$` sign looks quite interesting.)

Answer (score 12):

You can use `printf` for rounding:

```
$ printf "%.0f" 2743410360.320
```

Comment: In `bash` 4.1 the builtin `printf` says “invalid number”. Works fine with `/usr/bin/printf`.

Comment: @manatwork Works for me with bash 4.1.5 on Debian squeeze and even bash 3.2.39 on Ubuntu 8.04.

Comment: Indeed. Works fine in `bash` 4.2. Or maybe the problem was not the version – the first try was on Cygwin.

Comment: I tried it is not working fine when i am passing a value  $ printf "%.0f" $gb

Comment: @manatwork: Are you using `%i` or `%.0f`? The former says 'invalid number' for me, the latter works.

Comment: @Flimzy, I am quite (though not 100%) sure it was `%.0f`. My bad, I not specified the patch level of the version. It works fine in `bash` 4.1.5, the oldest I currently have.

Answer (score 7):

I don't see an answer to @vin's problem, which is:

> But I am getting `(standard_in) 1: syntax error`

The `bc` command prints `(standard_in) 1: syntax error` because the shell variable `gb` is not set:

```
$ unset gb
$ echo "($gb+0.5)/1" | bc
(standard_in) 1: syntax error

$ gb=2743410360.320
$ echo "($gb+0.5)/1" | bc
2743410360
```

In the comments to the @dchirikov's answer, @vin says `printf "%.0f"` is "not working":

```
$ unset gb
$ printf '%.0f\n' $gb
0

$ gb=2743410360.320
$ printf '%.0f\n' $gb
2743410360
```

In both of the areas where @vin has problems, the unset variable reproduces the problem, and setting the variable solves the problem.

Answer (score 6):

```
$ p=2743410360.320
$ echo $p
2743410360.320
$ echo ${p%%.*}
2743410360
```

Comment: The `+0.5` in the original code looks like _rounding_ is needed.

Comment: simple - effective code

Comment: 5.9 rounded is not 5
This doesn't round at all.  Its chopping off everything after the decimal.

Answer (score 3):

Your command needs a couple of `( )`:

```
INTValueOfGB=$( echo "($gb+0.5)/1" | bc )
```

But that will not round the number, for that to work you need to set scale to 0:

```
INTValueOfGB=$( echo "scale=0;($gb+0.5)/1" | bc )
```

That will round up (from x.5) to the next integer.

To get "round to next even integer" (Banker's rule), you need to use printf rounding:

```
LC_NUMERIC=C printf "%.0f" 2743410360.320
```

The LC_NUMERIC is to ensure that numbers are processed with a dot as decimal.
That is not what users in Germany will like to use, this should work with decimals with `,`:

```
$ LC_NUMERIC=de_DE.utf8 printf "%.0f" 2743410360,320
2743410360
```